# What is the probability that a playoff series last 9 games, if the series terminate when a team got 5 wins?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Original question from AOPS:

> A playoff series between two teams proceeds one game at a time until one team has won 5 games. What is the probability that the series lasts 9 games if each team is equally likely to win each game?

I researched and found some solutions on the internet (which also gives the same answer as with the official solution) giving 35/128, taking 2^9 as the total number of possibilities.

The official solution seems to be counting 000000000,000000001,000000010,…,111111110,111111111 total of 512

My question is shouldn’t it count only
00000, 11111, 000010, 000100, 001000, 010000, 100000, …

and NOT including sequences like 000000000 because such game is not possibly?
In other words 000000000,000000001,000000010,…000001111 should all be just counted as 00000.

My Calculation shows that the answer should be

$$
\frac{\binom{8}{4}}{ 1+\binom{5}{1} +\binom{6}{2} +\binom{7}{3} +\binom{8}{4}  } 
$$

Comment: 00000 and 010101010 are not equally likely.

Comment: Even if the winner has been determined because someone has won $5$ times, let the two teams keep playing until they have played $9$ times.

Comment: Thanks very much aTree! That 2^9 is deceptively simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comments that show why outcomes you are counting are not equally probable, in the way you are thinking, it is easier to see how play doesn't last $9$ games.

That is either of the team wins in $5, 6, 7$ or $8$ games.

$P(W \leq 8) =  \displaystyle \frac {2}{2^5} + \frac {2 \cdot{5 \choose 4} } {2^6} + \frac{2 \cdot{6 \choose 4}}{2^7} + \frac {2 \cdot{7 \choose 4}}{2^8} = \frac{93}{128}$

So the probability that the play lasts $9$ games is $\displaystyle \frac{35}{128}$

But it is of course unnecessary when you can simply use $~\displaystyle \frac{2 \cdot {8 \choose 4}}{2^9}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is *given* that the match lasts for $9$ games, both teams must have won $4$ games each in $8$ games out of $2^8$ possible outcomes, and the last game won by *someone*

Thus ans = $\frac{\binom84}{2^8}= \frac{35}{128}$

Answer (score 1):

Putting an answer from the comments into an answer post where it belongs.

00000 and 010101010 aren't equality likely. To get outcomes that are equally likely, they change the rules of the playoff so that the teams always play nine games even if it's already been decided.

This change doesn't affect the probability that the series will be decided before the ninth game, but it will get them 512 equally likely possible outcomes.